# IMAPLIB - timeout eror

Tags: python, imaplib, timeoutexception

I download Email attachments with Python once per week.
It was working for more than one year without any problems.
But since one week, I get a `TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out`

I didn't change anything in the code. The only thing that has changed is my Outlook password, but I've adapted this in the code (I can access my emails in Outlook without any problems).

Any ideas how to deal with this error?

I run the code in a Jupyter notebook in Chrome (Mac).

This is my code:

```
import email
import imaplib
import os
server = 'outlook.office.com' 
user = 'florian.xcvh@jiko.ch'
password = 'XXXXYYY'
outputdir = '/Users/florian/Documents/weekly_data'
subject = 'Interesting stuff' #subject line of the emails you want to download attachments from

# Connect to an IMAP server
def connect(server, user, password):
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
    m.login(user, password)
    m.select()
    return m

# Download all attachment files for a given email
def downloaAttachmentsInEmail(m, emailid, outputdir):
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(BODY.PEEK[])")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)
    if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        return
    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart' and part.get('Content-Disposition') is not None:
            open(outputdir + '/' + part.get_filename(), 'wb').write(part.get_payload(decode=True))

#download attachments from all emails with a specified subject line
def downloadAttachments(subject):
    m = connect(server, user, password)
    m.select("Inbox")
    typ, msgs = m.search(None, '(SUBJECT "' + subject + '")')
    msgs = msgs[0].split()
    for emailid in msgs:
        downloaAttachmentsInEmail(m, emailid, outputdir)

downloadAttachments(subject)
```

Comment: Do you ever delete messages?

Comment: Yes, I delete all messages automatically after downloading the attachments.